Mitigate dependency vulnerabilities in codebase
When using IntelliJ to package a Java app, a Checkmarx-powered feature or plugin checks for vulnerabilities. However, we mitigate the vulnerabilities in our codebase instead of updating dependencies.
What would be the best way to update the project information in IntelliJ not to throw the warning again since we have tested and mitigated the vulnerability in our codebase?
The available option "Report false positive..." does not seem right to us.

Do you use any build system like Maven or Gradle? Do you use any form of reporting on the vulnerabilities where you want to annotate that you mitigated the problem yourself?
(I'm just not aware how with plain IntelliJ you would "package a Java app")

not updating is a stupid decision. always update if the opportunity arises. you can disable the security checks altogether by disabling the plugin providing them.

It seems that using the Ignore vulnerable ... option could potentially help here.
How to do this step by step:

use the tooltip for a specific vulnerable dependency
choose Ignore vulnerable <DEPENDENCY_NAME>: choosing option
specify the reason, like Not exploitable, Fixed in branch, or whatever: specifying the reason

You can do the same from the menu Settings -> Editor -> Inspections -> Vulnerable declared dependency: ignoring via settings menu
I hope this helps!
